# Get SVG with styles from HTML/CSS using Python 3

Tags: python, html, svg, beautifulsoup

SVG I want to retrieve uses some custom classes so if I copypaste and save it in a file as is, obviously it loses styles. Can I extract SVG correctly somehow?

```
<svg class="stroke_order_diagram--svg_container_for_51866286d5dda7965800056a" style="height: 100px; width: 300px;" viewBox="0 0 300 100"><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs><line x1="1" x2="299" y1="1" y2="1" class="stroke_order_diagram--bounding_box"></line><line x1="1" x2="1" y1="1" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--bounding_box"></line><line x1="1" x2="299" y1="99" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--bounding_box"></line><line x1="0" x2="300" y1="50" y2="50" class="stroke_order_diagram--guide_line"></line><line x1="50" x2="50" y1="1" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--guide_line"></line><line x1="99" x2="99" y1="1" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--bounding_box"></line><path id="kvg:04e08-s1" kvg:type="㇐" d="M19.25,38.23c3.07,1.12,6.86,0.63,10.02,0.24c15.11-1.84,33.86-4.18,47.24-4.94c3.41-0.2,6.88-0.37,10.24,0.36" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-4,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--current_path"></path><path id="Sjkg29fknc" kvg:type="㇐" d="M19.25,38.23c3.07,1.12,6.86,0.63,10.02,0.24c15.11-1.84,33.86-4.18,47.24-4.94c3.41-0.2,6.88-0.37,10.24,0.36" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-4,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--current_path"></path><circle cx="19.25" cy="38.23" r="4" class="stroke_order_diagram--path_start" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-4,-4)"></circle><line x1="150" x2="150" y1="1" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--guide_line"></line><line x1="199" x2="199" y1="1" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--bounding_box"></line><path id="Sjkg29fknf" kvg:type="㇐" d="M19.25,38.23c3.07,1.12,6.86,0.63,10.02,0.24c15.11-1.84,33.86-4.18,47.24-4.94c3.41-0.2,6.88-0.37,10.24,0.36" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,96,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--existing_path"></path><path id="kvg:04e08-s2" kvg:type="㇒" d="M52.77,15.18c1.21,1.21,1.48,2.57,1.55,5.42C55.25,56.75,49.75,78,16.5,95" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,96,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--current_path"></path><path id="Sjkg29fknh" kvg:type="㇒" d="M52.77,15.18c1.21,1.21,1.48,2.57,1.55,5.42C55.25,56.75,49.75,78,16.5,95" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,96,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--current_path"></path><circle cx="52.77" cy="15.18" r="4" class="stroke_order_diagram--path_start" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,96,-4)"></circle><line x1="250" x2="250" y1="1" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--guide_line"></line><line x1="299" x2="299" y1="1" y2="99" class="stroke_order_diagram--bounding_box"></line><path id="Sjkg29fknk" kvg:type="㇐" d="M19.25,38.23c3.07,1.12,6.86,0.63,10.02,0.24c15.11-1.84,33.86-4.18,47.24-4.94c3.41-0.2,6.88-0.37,10.24,0.36" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,196,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--existing_path"></path><path id="Sjkg29fknl" kvg:type="㇒" d="M52.77,15.18c1.21,1.21,1.48,2.57,1.55,5.42C55.25,56.75,49.75,78,16.5,95" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,196,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--existing_path"></path><path id="kvg:04e08-s3" kvg:type="㇏" d="M27.25,51.25c5.44,1.3,30.3,22.94,48.57,34.71c4.6,2.96,9.37,5.71,14.43,7.79" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,196,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--current_path"></path><path id="Sjkg29fknn" kvg:type="㇏" d="M27.25,51.25c5.44,1.3,30.3,22.94,48.57,34.71c4.6,2.96,9.37,5.71,14.43,7.79" xmlns:kvg="http://kanjivg.tagaini.net" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,196,-4)" class="stroke_order_diagram--current_path"></path><circle cx="27.25" cy="51.25" r="4" class="stroke_order_diagram--path_start" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,196,-4)"></circle></svg>
```

By the way if I try to retrieve SVG using BeautifulSoup I get only outer tag without inner ones for some reason:

```
<svg class="stroke_order_diagram--svg_container_for_51866286d5dda7965800056a" style="display: none; height: 100px"></svg>
```

I tried `html.parser` and `lxml` parsers, always the same result.

Comment: What do you mean it loses style? You need to have corresponding CSS definitions to know what each class in each tag means. BeautifulSoup won't help you with that.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, I guessed it can't help. But there should be something that can retrieve css or whatever and replace class name with actual styles in svg tag, maybe.